# how to check some check box with press shift

Tags: javascript, php, checkbox

i have some checkbox here

[image: checkbox]

its the code

```
<input type="checkbox" class="noreg" name="noreg[]" value="111006">
<input type="checkbox" class="noreg" name="noreg[]" value="111007">
<input type="checkbox" class="noreg" name="noreg[]" value="111008">
<input type="checkbox" class="noreg" name="noreg[]" value="111009">
<input type="checkbox" class="noreg" name="noreg[]" value="111010">
```

i want to check some checkbox with hold shift button like in phpmyadmin

[image]

can somebody help me for this?
thanks!

Comment: you need js for it, by checking one checkbox all values are checked. Just like `check all feature`

Comment: nothing to do with php here

Comment: @Nehal I 've added a feature select all but my boss would like to feature with the shift key

Comment: @sinaza , i know i have to use javascript , but how?
can you help me?

Comment: Checkout this it might  be resourceful [Shift Select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847604/selecting-multiple-elements-using-shift-and-mouse-click-jquery)

Comment: thanks for all your help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible with PHP but you achieve the same with jQuery.

```js
$(".master-noreg").change(function () {
    var boolIsChecked = false;
    if ($(this).is(":checked"))
    {
        boolIsChecked = true;
    }
    $(".noreg").prop("checked", boolIsChecked);
});
$(".noreg").change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked"))
    {
        if ($(".noreg").length == $(".noreg:checked").length)
        {
            $(".master-noreg").prop("checked", true);
        }
    } 
    else
    {
        $(".master-noreg").prop("checked", false);
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="master-noreg">Check All<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" class="noreg" name="noreg[]" value="111006">1<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" class="noreg" name="noreg[]" value="111007">2<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" class="noreg" name="noreg[]" value="111008">3<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" class="noreg" name="noreg[]" value="111009">4<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" class="noreg" name="noreg[]" value="111010">5<br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in parsing these multiple checkboxes then your current HTML code will give you an array which you can read with a foreach loop like this:

```
$noreg = $_POST["noreg"];

foreach( $noreg as $key => $value ){
    // your code here 
}


// Or if you want a string (comma delimeted):
$noreg_str = join( "," , $noreg );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in two steps (and I assuming, you use jQuery):

1) Make selection (select rows):

```
var shiftHold = false, rangeStart = null;
$(body).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == <shift>) { // put actual 'Shift'-press detection here
        shiftHold = true;
        rangeStart = null;
    }
});

$('.noreg[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
    var rangeEnd = this;
    if (rangeStart == null) {
        rangeStart = this;
    }

    // here you must check that 'rangeStart' element goes before 'rangeEnd'
    // or reverse them if needed

    rangeStart = $(rangeStart);
    var endVal = $(rangeEnd).val();
    while (rangeStart) {
       rangeStart.addClass("selected");
       if (rangeStart.val() == endVal )
           break;
       rangeStart = rangeStart.next('.noreg[type=checkbox]');
    }
});
```

2) Now, when you can select rows with pressed 'Shift', add another checkbox at bottom of them, and check selected rows when it clicked:

Slighest change to html:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="noreg" name="noreg[]" value="111006">
...
<input type="checkbox" class="noreg" name="noreg[]" value="111010">
...
<input type="checkbox" class="check-sel">Check selected
```

..and additional handler:

```
$('.check-sel').change(function () {
    var checked = $(this).is(":checked");
    $('.noreg.selected[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
        $(this).prop("checked", checked);
    });
});
```