# jQuery table row selected css shared with 2 different background colored rows needing to separate

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

Hey all I am stuck trying to figure out how to change the selected property **box-shadow** when I **click on a row**.

[image]

I could do this:

```
$('#grdSocialMediaFeeds').on('click', 'tr', function () {
  if ($(this)[0].style.backgroundColor == "") {
     //the rows background is white
     console.log("white");
     $(this).css('box-shadow',"inset 0 0 2px 2px #a7957f"); //Greyish color
  } else {
     //the rows background is red.
     console.log("red");
     $(this).css('box-shadow',"inset 0 0 2px 2px #a92525"); //Dark red-ish color
  }
});
```

And that does work fine putting the correct color box-shadow around the row I clicked on.

If it was a row that has a **red** background then I would put a darker **red box-shadow** around it when the user clicked/selected that row.

[image]

If it was a row that has a **white** background then I would put a **greyish box-shadow** around it when the user clicked/selected that row.

[image]

Now the **problem being** that if I go and select another cell (**white or red background**) then the **previously clicked row is still considered as still being the selected row** and therefore its **still has the box-shadow** and now the **"real" selected row also has the box-shadow** applied to it.

[image]

**To make things more complicated** (than they really should be), both the **white** background and **red** background rows share the same `tr.k-master-row.k-state-selected` css property. And you can **select more than one row** using the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd> means.

[image]

Is there any way/trick via **jQuery** that I can **un-select** whatever previous selected row(s) and have it only show the box-shadow on what the current user row(s) selected?

Comment: It appears as though you're using some kind of framework for this table? What's adding the "k-state-selected" class to the row? It seems like it would be easier to just add the CSS to that class than adding it via JavaScript...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way/trick via jQuery that I can un-select whatever previous selected row(s)

You've already described the solution in plain language, you just need to implement it in JS! :-) Here's a working snippet:

```js
$('#grdSocialMediaFeeds').on('click', 'tr', function () {

    // First remove highlight from all rows
    $('#grdSocialMediaFeeds tr').css('box-shadow', 'none');

    // Now add the highlight to the clicked row
    if ($(this)[0].style.backgroundColor == "") {
        $(this).css('box-shadow',"inset 0 0 2px 2px #a7957f");
    } else {
        console.log("red");
        $(this).css('box-shadow',"inset 0 0 2px 2px #a92525");
    }
});
```

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
td {
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="grdSocialMediaFeeds">
    <tr>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>Something</td>
        <td>AnotherThing</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: #f1c0e8;">
        <td>01/03/2022</td>
        <td>Public</td>
        <td>admin</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>01/03/2022</td>
        <td>admin</td>
        <td>admin</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>01/03/2022</td>
        <td>Public</td>
        <td>Public</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You really should be using CSS, rather than inline styles, and it is even a bit simpler when you do, here's an example of how you could do that:

```js
$('#grdSocialMediaFeeds').on('click', 'tr', function () {

    // First remove highlight from all rows
    $('#grdSocialMediaFeeds tr').removeClass('highlighted');

    // Now add the highlight to the clicked row
    $(this).addClass('highlighted');
});
```

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
td {
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

.white {
    background-color: #eee;
}

.pink {
    background-color: #f1c0e8;
}

.white.highlighted {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px 2px #a7957f;
}
.pink.highlighted {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px 2px #a92525;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="grdSocialMediaFeeds">
    <tr>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>Something</td>
        <td>AnotherThing</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="pink">
        <td>01/03/2022</td>
        <td>Public</td>
        <td>admin</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="white">
        <td>01/03/2022</td>
        <td>admin</td>
        <td>admin</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="white">
        <td>01/03/2022</td>
        <td>Public</td>
        <td>Public</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

> To make things more complicated (than they really should be) ... you can select more than one row using the Shift+click or Ctrl+click means.

Yep, that complicates things.  However there are plenty of examples of how to do that here on SO - here's one: [selecting multiple elements using shift and mouse click - jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847604/selecting-multiple-elements-using-shift-and-mouse-click-jquery)

So using that approach:

- if it is a plain click, first remove all `highlight`ed rows, and then add the `highlighted` class to the clicked row (we've already done this part);
- if it is a shift-click, add the `highlighted` class to the clicked row, without removing any current highlights;
- but what if it is already highlighted on shift-click?  In that case we want to remove the highlight from the clicked row, without removing any *other* current highlights;

Here's a working snippet demonstrating that:

```js
$('#grdSocialMediaFeeds').on('click', 'tr', function (e) {

    if (! e.shiftKey) {
        // If it was a plain click (ie NOT a shift-click), remove all
        // highlights, and highlight this row
        $('#grdSocialMediaFeeds tr').removeClass('highlighted');
        $(this).addClass('highlighted');
        
    } else {
        // If it was a shift-click, and the row was already hightlighted,
        // we want to unhighlight it.  If it was not already highlighted,
        // we want to highlight it.  So simply toggling that class:
        $(this).toggleClass('highlighted');
    }
});
```

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
td {
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

.white {
    background-color: #eee;
}

.pink {
    background-color: #f1c0e8;
}

.white.highlighted {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px 2px #a7957f;
}
.pink.highlighted {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px 2px #a92525;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="grdSocialMediaFeeds">
    <tr>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>Something</td>
        <td>AnotherThing</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="pink">
        <td>01/03/2022</td>
        <td>Public</td>
        <td>admin</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="white">
        <td>01/03/2022</td>
        <td>admin</td>
        <td>admin</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="white">
        <td>01/03/2022</td>
        <td>Public</td>
        <td>Public</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```